# LibreOffice Writer cannot open docx4j output

Tags: java, libreoffice, docx4j

I created an empty document with docx4j (docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl 11.1.0):

```
var wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();    
Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File("test.docx"));
```

But when I open it with LibreOffice Writer, it says "Due to an unexpected error, LibreOffice crashed.".

This happens both with libreoffice-still-6.1.6-1 and with libreoffice-fresh-de-6.2.4-1 on Arch Linux. With Word 2016 on a Windows machine it works.

How can I save a .docx document with docx4j so that LibreOffice Writer can open it?

Comment: If it works on Word but not LibreOffice then it may be a bug on LO's side.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/NewDocxHelloWorld.java which creates a simple "Hello World" docx.

It opens fine on LO 6.2.4.2.0+ which is what I have right now on Manjaro Linux.

I created this using current master, which is essentially 11.1.0 (but for Java 8), plus a fix for https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues/357